# 正規表現である特定の文が０もしくは１の時

Tags: python3, 正規表現

> `'<div class="ex">[^/]*/em></div>'`
>   自分でパターンを作りました。しかし、下記の上しかマッチできません。下記にも合うようにつくりたいです。どうしたらいいでしょうか？/span>を0or1でやろうとおもったのですが、文自体に？を使うことができませんでした。

下記のパターンにマッチするように作りたいです。

```
'<div class="ex"><em>文字列</em></div>'
'<div class="ex"><span>文字列</span><em>文字列</em></div>'
```

Comment: non-greedy matching を使って `r'<div class="ex">.*?<em>.*?</em></div>'` でよろしいかと思います。

Comment: *と?を二つつなげるとどのような意味になるのでしょうか？<div class="ex">.*</em></div>と最初やったのですが、<div class="ex">以下のすべてにマッチしてしまいました。

Comment: 「最短マッチ」、つまり可能な限り短い文字列でのマッチングという意味になります。`?` を付けない場合(`.*`)では「最長マッチ」になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` の対象は`()`で囲むことができます。

「文字列」の部分にはタグが入らないのであれば、

```
'<div class="ex">(<span>[^<]*</span>)?<em>[^<]*</em></div>'
```

でしょうか。`<span>`や`<em>`の中に他のタグが入ったり、属性が入る可能性がある場合はうまくいきません。